# Form value getting truncated when using Request.Form[0]

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I have a JSON RPC handler in a .NET web application and have a GWT form posted to it with one of the text box having the following value:

*How would you define your stress level today (1=Least, 10=Most)?*

When I post the form to the server, FireBug shows that the JSON string has been truncated to:

*Least, 10=Most)?*

However when I put a break point in the RPC handler at the server and look at the HttpRequest.Form property, it still has the full string. However as soon as I try to access the name-value pairs by doing request.Form[0], I get the truncated string and obviously my JSON encoder then fails to decode the string. Any ideas why? 
EDIT: here is the method:

```
    public override string GetMethodName(HttpRequest request) {
        if (RpcUtils.IsGet(request)) {
            if (request.PathInfo.Length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            string functionName = request.PathInfo.Substring(1);
            return functionName;
        } else if (RpcUtils.IsPost(request)) {
            if (request.PathInfo.Length > 0) {
                // Not really a proper JSON-RPC request, but handle it anyway
                string functionName = request.PathInfo.Substring(1);
                return functionName;
            } else {
                // Real JSON-RPC request
                var jsonRpc = (Dictionary<string, object>)this.Decode(request.Form[0]);
                string functionName = (string)jsonRpc["method"];
                return functionName;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and the problem is at line:

**var jsonRpc = (Dictionary)this.Decode(request.Form[0]);**

Comment: Can you please post code over here?

Comment: Did you get the reason why it failed ?